# Slick slider not working in a flex container

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, slick.js

I'm trying to center vertically a slick carousel (*http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/*) in a column. So I use `display: flex; align-items: center;` on the column (container of the slick slider) but it breaks the slider.

So I have try to center the carousel with an absolute position or by using flexbox but they both breaks the slick slider.

I hope someone got a css/js/jquery solution for this issue :)

Here a fiddle of the issue : https://jsfiddle.net/victor_allegret/g3dsd78w/

(sorry I have an issue adding slick to the stack overflow snippet)

**HTML :**

```
<div class='flex-container'>

 <div class='single-item'>

  <div><h3>1</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2</h3></div>
  <div><h3>3</h3></div>
  <div><h3>4</h3></div>
  <div><h3>5</h3></div>
  <div><h3>6</h3></div>

 </div>

</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.flex-container {
 /* Using flexbox */
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 /*----*/
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 40px;
 height: 500px;
 width: 80%;
 color: #333;
 background: #419be0;
}

.slick-slide {
 text-align: center;
 color: #419be0;
 background: white;
}
```

**JS :**

```
$(".single-item").slick({
 dots: true
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this ? [With absolute position.](https://jsfiddle.net/StepBaro/g3dsd78w/2/)

```
.abs-container {
  position:absolute;

  height:140px;
  width:300px;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin:-70px 0 0 -150px;

  color: #333;
  background: #419be0;
}
```

[And this with FlexBox.](https://jsfiddle.net/StepBaro/g3dsd78w/3/)

```
.flex-container {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;

  /* Using flexbox */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: stretch;
    align-items: center;
  /*----*/

  color: #333;
  background: #419be0;
}
.flex-child {
    width: 300px;
    order: 0;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    align-self: center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='flex-container'>
    <div class='flex-child'>
      <div class='single-item'>
      .
      .
      .
```

Comment: I have the same issue using flexbox and `position: absolute; top: 50%`. Both break the slider i can't figure why :/

Comment: You see the edited JSFiddle on my answer ? It seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/StepBaro/g3dsd78w/2/

Comment: Realy sorry, i tried your solution without adding an height & width on the absolute wrapper. So now it work thanks a lot !
But I'm still wondering why it isn't working with only a `display: flex; align-items: center;`on the parent ?

Comment: @VictorAllegret Probably because the plugin refers to its own container to retrieve the size, and the "display: flex" fails. We should know the structure of the plugin well to understand the problem.

Comment: `{position: absoute; top: 0px; width:100%; height:100% }` on the parent element did the trick for me. Adding another ancestor to the parent, with at least  `{position:relative}` was good to avoid conditional `top:0px`to respect flex display.

Answer (score 0):

Got this issue recently. Worked for me adding `min-width: 0;` to the flex child item.

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    ...
}

.single-item {
    ...
    min-width: 0;
}
```

As of this github [discussion](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/2378#issuecomment-375673561).